# Snapcraft fails in Docker container when started by Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04, snapcraft

I'm trying to build a Snap package in Docker as a Jenkins stage (it just runs the build script) but I end up with this:

```
Sorry, Snapcraft ran into an error when trying to running through its
lifecycle that generated the following traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/snapcraft", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('snapcraft==2.42.1', 'console_scripts', 'snapcraft')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 716, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1037, in invoke
    return Command.invoke(self, ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 889, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/cli/_runner.py", line 79, in run
    ctx.forward(lifecyclecli.commands['snap'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 552, in forward
    return self.invoke(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/cli/lifecycle.py", line 135, in snap
    project_options, directory=directory, output=output)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/internal/lifecycle/_packer.py", line 46, in snap
    execute('prime', project_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/internal/lifecycle/_runner.py", line 60, in execute
    config = project_loader.load_config(project_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/internal/project_loader/__init__.py", line 31, in load_config
    return Config(project_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/internal/project_loader/_config.py", line 215, in __init__
    snapcraft_yaml = self._process_remote_parts(snapcraft_yaml)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/internal/project_loader/_config.py", line 355, in _process_remote_parts
    properties = self._remote_parts.get_part(after_part)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/internal/project_loader/_config.py", line 198, in _remote_parts
    self._remote_parts_attr = remote_parts.get_remote_parts()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/internal/remote_parts.py", line 83, in get_remote_parts
    return _RemoteParts()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/internal/remote_parts.py", line 140, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/internal/remote_parts.py", line 94, in __init__
    os.makedirs(self.parts_dir, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
```

So: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'`

Now the thing I don't understand is that if I run my build script manually it works:

```
CMD="export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && \
     export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 && \
     cd /heimer/packaging/snap && \
     snapcraft"

docker run --privileged -t -v $(pwd):/heimer juzzlin/qt5:16.04 bash -c "${CMD}"
```

This is how I run it in Jenkinsfile:

```
    stage('Snap package / Ubuntu 16.04') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'juzzlin/qt5:16.04'
                args '--privileged -t -v $WORKSPACE:/heimer'
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh "./scripts/buildSnap.sh"
        }
        post {
            always {
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'packaging/snap/*.snap', fingerprint: true
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the difference? Why does this fail when Jenkins runs it?

Comment: I think it might have to do with Docker plugin weren't able to assume Root. If you run the manual command in an `sh` block instead of the `docker{}` plugin. Do you still get the error?

Comment: Yeah, seems to work that way. I'm using `docker {}` to build all my other packages with various tools so I'm not sure what's so special in snapcraft.